# Tomcat domain name in webhost

Tags: apache, tomcat, web-applications, host

I have Tomcat private server, it works when using the server IP address like : 192.161.26.111:8080/etc

But when using my domain name it dosen't: www.domain.com:8080/etc

It gives me this error:

```
description The requested resource is not available.
```

I'm using tomcat7.

Comment: you have to create an entry in your hosts file for that to work.

Comment: another reason can be you haven't configured host in server.xml - http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/config/host.html

Answer (score 0):

You should connect your domain name with your server pointing its A record to it to access it via domain name. You also need to setup virtual host for it in Apache to work.